# Facebook Open Graph Image

Tags: facebook

Tenho o plugin social em um determinado website, e todos os dias as imagens miniaturas (Open Graph Image) são alteradas.

Todos os dias eu preciso entrar no URL: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

E inserir o meu URL, e clicar em "Fetch new Scrape Information".

Para que assim que um usuário do sistema quiser compartilhar o website no Facebook a imagem estivesse atualizada para que o Facebook atualize a Open Graph Image.

Como automatizar esse processo?

Comment: Em que linguagem?

Comment: Idéia randômica e inviável(?), seria legal se pudesse usar uma `imagem.png.php`

Comment: [How to Automate Repetitive Web Browser Tasks With iMacros](http://www.howtogeek.com/113789/how-to-automate-repetitive-web-browser-tasks-with-imacros/)

Comment: Eu deveria criar isto como um processo de forma que fosse executado juntamente com a alteração da imagem. 
E sobre o Imacros, teria que dar o comando para o mesmo executar essa rotina...

Comment: Brasofilo, a ideia randômica não funcionou, mas valeu! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a solução foi colocar o seguinte trecho de código na página:

```
$.post(
    'https://graph.facebook.com',
    {
        id: 'http://www.minhaurl.com.br',
        scrape: true
    },
    function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
);
```

Assim que um usuário entra na página, a imagem atualiza automaticamente.

Grato.